# Algorithm - Find the maximum number which is the sum of two numbers in an array

Tags: algorithm

Description:

Given an array consists of n positive integers, find the largest C which makes C=A+B. A,B,C are all in the given array.

Example:

1 1 1 4 5 5 6 6 10 9  C=10

1 3 6                 C=-1, This means the largest C does not exist

I'm looking for an algorithm which is less than O(n^3), Can anyone give me some directions?

Comment: Well, you could drop one loop and use a hashtable look-up instead.

Comment: Does this mean that A and B have to be different numbers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sort the list. Iterate over C from largest to smallest, and over B from smallest to the value of C. So far, it's O(n^2). For each (C, B) pair, calculate A, and you just need to find if it's in the array. You can use a binary search for an overall time of O(n^2 log n).

Answer (score 0):

O(n^2) is enough based on @valtron 's algorithm

Comment: I'm not able to understand. Could you explain in more detail?

Comment: @CookSchelling it's similar to valtron's algorithm. the only diffierence is that when iterate C and to find A and B, he uses binary search and overall time is O(n^2lgn), but my algorithm is to iterate C(O(n)), and then use O(n) to check whether exists A+B equals C. just use two pointers points to the smallest and biggest element, and move pointers accordingly

Answer (score 0):

**More efficient solution:**

> 1 1 1 4 5 5 6 6 9 10 10

- Sort the array
- keep 3 pointers C, B and A.
- Keeping C at the last and A at 0 index and B at 1st index.
- traverse the array **using pointers A and B** till C and check if A+B=C exists or not.
  If it exists then C is your answer.
- Else, **Move C a position back** and traverse again keeping A at 0 and B at 1st index.

Keep repeating this till you get the sum or C reaches at 1st index.

***Here's the complete solution:***

```
int arr[] = new int[]{1,1,1,4,5,5,6,6,10,9};
Arrays.sort(arr);

        int n=arr.length;
        int a,b,c,sum,max=-1;

        for(c=n-1;(c>1)&& (max==-1);c--){       // loop through C
            for(a=0;(a<c-1)&&(max==-1);a++){    // loop through A
                for(b=a+1;b<c;b++){             // loop through B
                    sum=arr[a]+arr[b];
                    if(sum==arr[c]){
                         System.out.println("A: "+arr[a]+" B: "+arr[b]);
                        max=arr[c];
                        break;
                    }
                    if(sum>arr[c]){ // no need to go further
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

System.out.println(max);
```